# Creating folder in network share fails with "bad path" error

Tags: vbscript, directory, wsh, network-share

I have a network share already setup. I am trying to create a VBScript that will create a folder in the share called `computername`, which is the PC's name. The script will run locally on the PC, access the share and create the folder in the share.

My error is "`bad path`". I'm guessing I can't just state the network share path?

My script is below:

```
Dim objShell
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
computername = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )

If NOT (objFSO.FolderExists("\\ServerPath\Share$" + computername)) Then
    objFSO.CreateFolder("\\ServerPath\Share$" + computername)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking a backslash between the name of the share and the name of the folder you want to create. Also, I'd recommend using a variable for the path, so you don't have to construct it multiple times.

Change this:

```
If NOT (objFSO.FolderExists("\\ServerPath\Share$" + computername)) Then
    objFSO.CreateFolder("\\ServerPath\Share$" + computername)
End If
```

into this:

```
path = "\\ServerPath\Share$\" & computername
If NOT objFSO.FolderExists(path) Then
    objFSO.CreateFolder(path)
End If
```

Comment: I'm now getting "The specified network name is no longer available.  I know the network name works fine. Is it due to the UNC path?

Comment: It is definitely possible to create a folder on a share using the UNC path

Comment: @BenjaminJones Verify that the share is actually available on the server (`net share`) and accessible on the client (`net use * \\server\share$`).